# Grid view click event for full image activity with auto resize images in android

Tags: android, grid

I have a code for grid view using "Layout Inflator". I want a code for click event in this through which I can open the full image in next activity. So I want click event code for this inflator, as I am not getting it.

**Here is my main image adapter code.**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

GridView gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
gridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));
}

private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public MyAdapter(Context context)
{
inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

items.add(new Item("Image 1", R.drawable.nature1));
items.add(new Item("Image 2", R.drawable.nature2));
items.add(new Item("Image 3", R.drawable.tree1));
items.add(new Item("Image 4", R.drawable.nature3));
items.add(new Item("Image 5", R.drawable.tree2));
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
return items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i)
{
return items.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i)
{
return items.get(i).drawableId;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
{
View v = view;
ImageView picture;
TextView name;

if(v == null)
{
v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, viewGroup, 
v.setTag(R.id.picture, v.findViewById(R.id.picture));
v.setTag(R.id.text, v.findViewById(R.id.text));
}

picture = (ImageView)v.getTag(R.id.picture);
name = (TextView)v.getTag(R.id.text);

Item item = (Item)getItem(i);

picture.setImageResource(item.name.setText(item.name);

return v;
}

private class Item
{
final String name;
final int drawableId;
Item(String name, int drawableId)
{
this.name = name;
this.drawableId = drawableId;
}
}
}
}
```

I have used below code for click event but it could not work. Please suggest some click event code for Layout Inflator

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View, int position, long id) {

// Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
// passing array index
i.putExtra("id", position);
startActivity(i);
}
});
```

Comment: set click listener for `v` in `getView` method and do what you want

Answer (score 0):

`setItemClickListener` to your gridview and override the `onItemClick` method

```
 gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                        int position, long id) {

                    // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
                    // passing array index
                    i.putExtra("id", position);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
```

Comment: This code is not working. As I have not used array so I have to pass the position of LayoutInflator. See my whole code.